# Python - Find sequence in array: start when two values below threshold, end when two values above threshold

Tags: python, sequence

I have an annual time series of a drought index (PDSI), with values ranging from -4 to +4. I am trying to define a drought event that begins with two consecutive years below a PDSI value of 0, and ends when there are two consecutive years greater than or equal to 0.

For instance, in this series of data:

```
ts = [-2, -2, -4,  0, -1,  0, -1,  1, -2,  2, -3, -2,  3,  1, -2, 
      -3, -4, -3,  3, -3, -3, -3, -1, -3,  3,  3, -4, -1, -1,  0]
```

*note: i tried posting an image to help visualize the problem, but my reputation isn't high enough*

By the drought definition above, there should be three droughts in this series:

1) Starting at year 0 and ending at year 11 (years 12 and 13 are `>=` 0)

2) Starting at year 14 and ending at year 23 (years 24 and 25 `>=` 0)

3) Starting at year 26 and ending at the end of the series: year 29. Even though this drought was not ended by two consecutive years `>=` 0, it is still ongoing and should be counted.

The return value could be an array like:

```
droughts = [[0, 11], [14, 23], [26, 29]]
```

This means excluding any potential subsets with two consecutive values of PDSI < 0. For instance, in the first sequence [0, 11], it is also true that [1,2] and [10,11] satisfy the 'two consecutive values below the threshold' rule. But, they should be ignored as they are part of a larger sequence.

**EDIT:**

Here is some code that works for defining first two droughts, but get hung up on the last one (I think it's looping infinitely). I'm pretty new to Python, and in addition to it the code not working, my guess is it's quite inefficient as well.

```
def find_droughts (array):
answer = []
i = 0
while i < len(array):
    if (array[i] < 0 and array[i+1] < 0):
        if i+1 >= len(array):
            i = len(array)
            end = i
            a.append([start, end])
            break
        else:
            start = i
            print "start = %s" %start
        for j in range(i+2, len(array)-1):
            if (array[j] >= 0 and array[j+1] >= 0):
                end = j-1
                a.append([start, end])
                print 'end=%s' %end
                i = j+2;
                break
            else:
                i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
return answer

find_droughts(ts)
```

And the output below. Had to interrupt the kernel since it's stuck in a loop.

```
start = 0
end=11
start = 14
end=23
start = 26
start = 27
start = 27
start = 27
start = 27
....
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried something yet? If yes, can you show the code?

Comment: I don't understand how the logic works - like when is the threshold not met with the 2 years negative - i.e., would [10,11] qualify as well?

Comment: @mauve, Hello! While  [10, 11] are both below zero, they should still be counted as part of the first drought event, which started at year 0 since [0, 1] = -2, -2.  The first drought event should stop if and only if there are two consecutive years >= 0. In this case, years [12, 13]. I would like the output, though, to not include [12,13] as part of the drought sequence. Rather, the end value of the sequence should be 11.

Comment: @JeanJung, Thanks! Yes, I'll post my failed solution after I clean it up a bit to make it presentable.

Comment: @matt my point is that that sequence meets the criteria - i.e., your qualifications aren't defined to exclude subsets that would be contained in a larger set.

Comment: @mauve I can see your point, and those subsets should be excluded. I'll modify the post to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
ts = [-2, -2, -4,  0, -1,  0, -1,  1, -2,  2, -3, -2,  3,  1, -2,
      -3, -4, -3,  3, -3, -3, -3, -1, -3,  3,  3, -4, -1, -1,  0]

# find positions of 2 consecutive negatives
neg = [i for i in range(len(ts)-1) if ts[i]<0 and ts[i+1] < 0]
print neg

# find locations of 2 consecutive positives + last year
pos = [i for i in range(len(ts)-1) if ts[i]>0 and ts[i+1] > 0] + [len(ts)]
print pos

# find the earliest neg for each pos
draughts = []
for p in pos:
    try:
        draughts.append((neg[0],p))
        neg = [n for n in neg if n > p]
    except IndexError:
        # no more negatives left, no draught in progress
        break

print draughts
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 10, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 26, 27]
[12, 24, 30]
[(0, 12), (14, 24), (26, 30)]
```

there are some off by ones and edge cases that need ironing out but overall...

here is an alternative method which requires only a single pass over `ts`:

```
ts = [-2, -2, -4,  0, -1,  0, -1,  1, -2,  2, -3, -2,  3,  1, -2,
      -3, -4, -3,  3, -3, -3, -3, -1, -3,  3,  3, -4, -1, -1,  0]

in_draught = False
draught = []

for i in range(len(ts)-1):
    if in_draught and ts[i] > 0 and ts[i+1] > 0:
        in_draught = False
        draught.append(i)
    elif not in_draught and ts[i] <0 and ts[i+1] < 0:
        in_draught = True
        draught.append(i)
if in_draught:
    draught.append(len(ts)-1)

print [draught[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(draught),2)]
```

output:

```
[[0, 12], [14, 24], [26, 29]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working pretty well on some real data. Being a Python newbie, I'll have to take some time to figure out what your solutions are doing.